# Variable and parameter names

Tags: c++

```
typedef enum {
MGL_TRIANGLES,
MGL_QUADS
} MGLpoly_mode;

MGLpoly_mode mode; //mode 1

void mglBegin(MGLpoly_mode mode)
{
mode = mode;  //mode 1 = input parameter mode
}
```

Does this code set "mode 1" equal to the input parameter called mode? If anyone could explain what happens here and other interesting caveats and workarounds that would be great! I'm just curious how this snippet of code works.

Comment: 1) One could just step through the code with a debugger, to figure out how any piece of code works. 2) What caveats, or workarounds are you asking about? This code, wouldn't even compile, since it lacks `main`, but regardless of that, the function `mglBegin` just assigns parameter passed in to it, to itself, with no observable side effects from the function-callers side of view. 3) Consider learning from a good book, instead of coding randomly (I am unsure whether you are coding in C, or C++, due to tags, so I can't recommend specific book list).

Comment: _Does this code set "mode 1" equal to the input parameter called mode?_  No, it sets the parameter `mode` to itself.

Comment: Questions should not be tagged both [c] and [c++], unless the question is specifically about a difference between them. They are different incompatible languages, so please just use the tag for the language you're actually using.

Comment: How could the compiler magically know that, on _the same line_, you wanted the same word to mean two different things?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: The code does not require `main` to compile.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, I stand corrected. Probably I just got too used to people asking mostly about executable applications here (opposed to libraries), that I forgot about those (and the question didn't show any signs of being compiled into library)..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: It doesn't matter whether your target deliverable is an executable or a library. At the compilation phase you do not need to define an entrypoint (indeed, you will only do so for _one_ of your compilation targets!). It is only later, during linking, that this becomes a consideration.

Comment: That's a terrible way to code!!  Use a different name for the parameter.  The parameter name in the definition (in the .c file) does not have to match the parameter name declared in the function declaration in the corresponding .h file.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The thought of adding a note regarding this, had crossed my mind, but I omitted it for brevity. One, typically might think of "compilation" as an act of producing an usable binary (i.e. library, executable, etc.). That's why I used in my initial comment, even if it is not "technically" correct. Could you suggest, other word, or phrase that conveys the meaning described above, and reads nicely?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: I believe you're referring to the "build" process ("building").

Comment: Am I getting downvoted because people think this is a bad way to write code? I asked this question for educational purposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local variable `mode` defined as an input parameter will always have precedence over the global variable, hence the statement you have written will accomplish nothing.
[EDIT] Assuming you are using c++, you can use the scope resolution operator to refer to the global variable

```
::mode = mode;  //mode 1 = input parameter mode
```

Comment: This question is tagged with C, in addition to C++, so it is unclear, with what compiler the OP is compiling the code, and C doesn't have scope resolution operator.

Comment: so Sanchit Anand's answer only works in C++? Is there a way to do this in C?

Comment: @TariqueShams • Use a different parameter name than the global variable name.  Works both in C and in C++.

Comment: @Elijay That is the easy fix. I believe I should follow that structure too. Im just curious if there is a cool work around?

Comment: @TariqueShams Nope. You'll find some C coding standards require you to modify the name of a variable depending on its scope and storage type. For example, that global `mode` could be `gmode` and parameter mode is `pmode`. Others require more decoration such as prefixing the variable with a module identifier, roughly (very roughly) emulating namespaces and preventing name collisions across translation units. Also makes plaintext searching a lot easier.